# How to modify a global variable inside a function in javascript, i.e. modify variable in-place

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, global-variables

So, below you can find my (very basic and unoptimized) solution to [Leetcode's challenge 189 'Rotate Array'](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/).
The target of this challenge is posed as follows: Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.

Now, my solution is not accepted as somehow the global variable nums remains unchanged after the function call. Why is that? Somehow nums is treated as local variable and doesn't change the passed-in global variable nums. I get that it's probably because of how javascript treats variable scopes but I don't seem to find resources that can help me understand this example.

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} k
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
 */
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
    array2 = Array.from(nums)
    nums.map((num) => {
        array2[(nums.indexOf(num)+k)%nums.length] = num
    })
    nums = Array.from(array2)
    console.log(nums) // returns expected answer
};
```

```
Your input
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
3

Your stdout
[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]

Your answer
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Expected answer
[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: "*Somehow nums is treated as local variable*" - that's because you declared it as a function parameter

Comment: That..makes sense, function parameters are treated as local variables inside functions then. Still, I don't get how my answer isn't accepted as I am clearly modifying the local variable as stated in the exercise, no?

Comment: What the exercise *means* by "*modify `nums` in-place*" is that you should mutate (modify) the array *object* that is held by `nums` (ie that is passed in for the `nums` parameter), not that you should assign (modify) the local `nums` variable which has no effect outside of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function does not modify the original array. Additionally, you seem to be using it incorrectly.

You are using `map` to set the values of `array2` and then setting `nums` to a copy of `array2`. This will not modify the original object contained in `nums`.

Of course, if you log `nums` within the function, it will give you the updated value, but this value is scoped within the function and won't be accessible outside.

Instead of array methods, for this type of impure programming, you should use a for loop.

```js
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
    array2 = Array.from(nums);
    for (const i in nums) nums[i] = array2[(i+k)%nums.length];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but here is the issue:

```js
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
    array2 = Array.from(nums)
    nums.map((num) => {
        array2[(nums.indexOf(num)+k)%nums.length] = num //Making changed to array2
    })
    nums = Array.from(array2) //Completely changing the reference of nums
    console.log(nums) // returns expected answer
};

let nums =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
rotate(nums,3); 
console.log(nums); //Original nums still as it is
```

If you look at the above code, `nums` is actually not changing. Reason being you are creating a completely new array `array2`. Inside your `.map()`, you are making all sorts of changing to it and assigning that back again to `nums`. But the reference of the original `nums` is unchanged.

You should actually be making change to your `nums` and using `array2` for help:

```js
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
        array2 = Array.from(nums)
        array2.forEach((num) => {
        nums[(array2.indexOf(num)+k)%array2.length] = num
        })
        console.log(nums) // returns expected answer
    };

let nums =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    rotate(nums,3);
    console.log(nums);
```

PS: `.map()` is when you want a new transformed array returned. Otherwise you can simply use `.forEach`, or a for loop.